# Magento 2 update subtotal item

Tags: php, magento, magento2, checkout, subtotal

In Magento 2, on the checkout page where the cart items are displayed, when I modify the quantity to be higher than the available stock, only the available quantity (stock quantity) is shown. However, I notice that the subtotal calculation is incorrect as it is based on the desired quantity rather than the displayed quantity ( stock quantity) .
Furthermore, if I order another product and modify its quantity, I observe that the subtotal for the first product is displayed correctly, taking into account the displayed value (stock quantity).

I adjusted the entered quantity to the stock quantity if the entered quantity is greater than the stock quantity.

I want to give an example. I have a product with a unit price of $100 and a stock quantity of 1300. I want to order 1500 (1500 > 1300). The system displays 1300 in the quantity field (the stock quantity), but the subtotal calculation is incorrect: $150,000 (1500 * $100), whereas I want the subtotal to be $130,000 (1300 * $100) because I displayed 1300.

This is the code in the default.phtml file of the checkout module.

```
<td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>">
<div class="field qty">
    <div class="control qty">
        <label for="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty">
            <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>
            <input id="cart-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>-qty"
                   name="cart[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>][qty]"
                   data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>"
                   value="<?=  $block->getQty() > $qty_stock ? $qty_stock : $block->getQty(); ?>"
                   type = "number"
                   size="4"
                   step="any"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                   class="input-text qty"
                   data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                   data-item-qty="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getQty()) ?>"
                   data-role="cart-item-qty"
                   data-row-total="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRowTotal($_item)) ?>"
            />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```